Is it impossible to launch a rocket from Venus’ surface to space?
This very thoughtful question points out there are limits to launching chemical rockets, particularly due to a planet’s gravity:
How much bigger could Earth be, before rockets wouldn't work?
A related question could be, "How much denser could Earth's atmosphere be before rockets wouldn't work?" For instance, if Earth's atmosphere were as dense as Venus, chemical rockets would have a very tough time getting into orbit.
On Venus, rockets get a 10% break on gravity compared with Earth, but Venus's atmospheric density is much higher.
https://www.nature.com/articles/ngeo2971#:~:text=At%20the%20surface%20of%20Venus,(refs%203%2C4)

Atmospheric density at the surface is about 65 kg m−3 or 6.5% the
density of liquid water.

Or about 54x that of Earth. High atmospheric density will lower MaxQ and dramaticaly increase gravity loss.
Rocket nozzle design would be a headache and fuel storage at high ambient temperature would rule out cryogenics, putting a limit on isp.
If we are ever to get a sample return from Venus, a rocket launch from some altitude in the Venusian atmosphere will be necessary. Is it physically possible?

related: Launch to orbit delta-v penalty from Venus compared to Earth? it certainly seems challenging!

I thought the actual problem was the corrosive atmosphere; otherwise this should work (estimating loss risk exceeds my ability) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ONP9jS14toE

It would be physically possible, but there's no practical way to do it just with chemically-propelled rockets. The extremely high density of the atmosphere caps the top speed of the rocket until it's at high altitude, exacerbating gravity loss, so you'd need a ridiculous propellant mass ratio. (At only 100mph, the dynamic pressure at low altitude is comparable to the supersonic max-Q of a terrestrial rocket launch.)
What could conceivably work would be to use balloon ascent to get up to a high altitude "for free" and then use a chemical rocket from there. Designing and engineering something that can land, collect samples, inflate a balloon in the Venusian surface environment, and conduct an interplanetary launch from there is left as an exercise for the reader.

You could simplify the lander by having it balloon up to launch altitude and then dock with another balloon (which you had launched separately) holding the return rocket, assuming that you can reliably get two untethered balloons to rendezvous, on Venus. (That doesn't sound a lot simpler, does it?)

Yeah the lander could be lighter that way, but ooof that complicates the overall mission design a lot.

Although Venus doesn't have winds driven by rotation, its wind speeds aren't exactly low. https://space.stackexchange.com/a/10872/38535 has a graph of Venus wind speed vs altitude. Also, those winds carry a lot of momentum, due to the high density.

also left as an exercise (now why did I initially type exorcism) for the reader is finding a way to create a volume of gas light and large enough to lift your return vehicle, and a balloon design that can stabilise the return vehicle's launcher in the Venusian wind.

@jwenting don't forget being chemically resilient to sulfuric acid at 700 K

@llama minor detail once you've overcome everything else ;)

Unconsidered alternatives, in order of increasing infeasibility:  (1) nuclear-thermal rocket; (2) mass-driver; (3) space elevator.  How much are you willing to spend on this mission?
If atmosphere samples are all that's wanted, a grazing flyby would do, if the materials are available.

It would probably be better to just lower the sample collector from a tether, and leave the ascent rocket with the balloon.

NTR has poor thrust-to-weight; mass-driver would have an even worse time with the dynamic pressure/heating issue, as it needs to deliver maximum velocity at minimum altitude; I have nothing constructive to say about space elevators.

@qazwsx "Depth 32,000 fathoms, Captain; sand and acid-etched shell."

@MarkWood don't forget Orion drives!

@MarkWood How do you do a space elevator on a planet with a (sidereal) rotation period of ~243 days? I guess you could use the L1 Lagrange point...

Hmmm I don't get why you don't take off horizontally and fly on aerodynamic lift until the atmospheric density corresponds to 30,000 feet earth.

@Joshua That begs the question of how you power an air-breathing engine in an atmosphere that's predominantly $CO_2$...

They didn't say anything about air-breathing.

@RussellBorogove You wouldn't pass down the chance of pushing back against all that heavy atmosphere. There'll be an air-breathing propeller/turbine involved somewhere. But the air-breathing breakes down when you get to burning fuel, which was precisely my point. So, you "just" have to get creative about how you power that prop...

@jwenting: How difficult would it be to design aparatus to convert 2CO2+Energy -> 2CO + O2?  The molecular weight of CO is less than 2/3 that of CO2, and from what I understand CO2 would be plentiful.

@supercat: It might be simpler to just use a hot-air (OK, hotter Venus atmosphere) balloon. No idea what you make the envelope out of, though. Kevlar won't take the temperatures involved.

@JohnDallman: Achieving the same lift with a hot-atmospheric-gas balloon in 700C ambient would require heating the gas by almost 500C beyond that.

@cmaster-reinstatemonica: Ah; air intake for reaction gas maybe, but powered like a rocket with bottled propellants. But yeah I didn't think quite that far.

Remember Venus surface temperature, too. Some scientists are actually trying to reinvent mechanical computing as a way to have logic that would survive under those conditions. Prototypes so far have the standard problems of overcoming friction

@RussellBorogove Typical NTR has poor thrust to weight, but if the acid problem could be dealt with somehow an unshielded nuclear thermojet could probably take advantage of the higher atmospheric density for more thrust.  A nuclear saltwater rocket has possibilities too.  All the things you can do when you're not terribly worried about rendering the planet uninhabitable...
