How much denser could Earth's atmosphere be before rockets wouldn't work?
As the atmosphere gets denser, any rocket trying to fly through it would experience more and more atmospheric drag. How much denser could Earth's atmosphere be before rockets wouldn't work (or would necessitate a rocket to be implausibly/impossibly large)?
Let's use all the same rules/assumptions from this question and its accepted answer. Let's also assume that our rocket starts out as a normal Saturn V (but making it bigger to get through the denser atmosphere does still affect its aerodynamics). Let's also assume this atmosphere is the same as Earth's current atmosphere except with 100 times the density.

Similar to https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/67233/is-it-impossible-to-launch-a-rocket-from-venus-surface-to-space

Humans and mammals could not live in an atmosphere with 100 times the density. The question does not make sense.

@Uwe We are talking about the constraints on rockets. Obviously the humans building them would have some issues, we are ignoring that.

I'm feeling like rockoons would be a good solution to this problem. Lift the rocket on balloons high enough that the loss of buoyancy balances with rise of thrust and the rocket can fly normally.

"Implausibly large" is a matter of perspective...

@DarthPseudonym I guess implausibly large is sort of opinion, but what I meant by implausible is "maybe technically possible but not something that could ever reasonably happen", like "yeah this rocket could work but it would be 1% of the mass of the whole planet".

@SF. Yeah that probably would be a pretty good idea (for the purposes of this question though I'm assuming normal rockets)

Interesting! I sometimes ask a pair of questions (each links to the other as a "companion question"). In this case you ask here about rockets from the surface. You could also ask an independent companion question only about hybridized alternatives (rockoons, aircraft-launch, etc.) I think both questions are reasonable and would have interesting and independent answers.

T = m*ve + Ae(P1−P2) where T is thrust, m is the mass flow rate, v is the exhaust velocity, A is the area of the exhaust jet at the exit plane, P1 is the chamber pressure and P2 is the  atmospheric pressure. Raptor has a chamber pressure of around 270bar, with a 100bar back pressure its going to make a huge difference. As rockets can only just reach orbit as it is I doubt it would be possible at 100atm pressure. At 271atm atmospheric pressure would exceed Raptor chamber pressure so it would not work at all (and it would probably stop working long before then unless adjusted big time)

@Slarty Let's remember this is a Saturn V. The F-1 has a chamber pressure of 70 bar so 100 atm definitely won't work.

For sure it would be a big bada boom
